# Stack panel reorder

Tags: wpf, vb.net, forms, children, stackpanel

I've created an app that allows people to create shortcuts easily.
I have a button that is clicked to open a new window where the user enters a name for their shortcut, they then paste a directory of this shortcut and create it.

This writes to a text document on a drive which lists the btnName and bntDir.
It then goes on to create a button on a dashboard with the name that they've given. This is done using a stack panel. I need them to be able to move their shortcuts as they please within the stack panel. Please help

Comment: I would create an object that represents a button & it's action, and use an ItemsControl to display an ObservableCollection of those objects. This would allow you to filter, re-order etc.

Comment: You need re-ordering items in a stackpanel ? Does this re-ordering should affect actual shortcuts in your text document ?